# How to conditionally identify identical & distinct species observations within a column

Tags: r, unique

I am trying to identify which species observations are identical and different between aboveground and belowground sampling plots. I am basically looking to get the data that would go into a Venn diagram

Some example data is below. I am looking to find which species are identical between aboveground and belowground in 2013 (RUBUS & VITIS are shared between aboveground and belowground) and then which are not shared (ACTA & ARTR for 2013 aboveground; BOCY & VIOLA for 2013 belowground). So, conditionally identifying distinct and identical observations within a column.

```
Year <- c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013)
Layer <- c(aboveground, aboveground, aboveground, aboveground, belowground, belowground, belowground, belowground)
Species <- c(ACTA, ARTR, RUBUS, VITIS, BOCY, RUBUS, VIOLA, VITIS)

df <- c(Year, Layer, Species)

df %>% unique(Layer = Species) #Shot in the dark solution as I feel like the answer is going to be quite simple
```

I thought either filtering or an ifelse function would work, but thus far I have had no luck. Several of the Venn diagram functions in R are clunky and don't give the actual similar observations between variables

Comment: Could you please correct your sample data code so it will run? All the strings need quotes.

Comment: It would also be nice to show the desired result for this sample input to make sure things are clear

Answer (score 1):

```
attr(gplots::venn(as.list(unstack(df, Species~Layer)),show.plot = FALSE), 'intersections')

$aboveground
[1] "ACTA" "ARTR"

$belowground
[1] "BOCY"  "VIOLA"

$`aboveground:belowground`
[1] "RUBUS" "VITIS"
```

where

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013), Layer = c("aboveground", "aboveground", "aboveground", 
"aboveground", "belowground", "belowground", "belowground", "belowground"
), Species = c("ACTA", "ARTR", "RUBUS", "VITIS", "BOCY", "RUBUS", 
"VIOLA", "VITIS")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```